# MS Access DB file stored in a shared drive opens very slow when accessed from a remote location

Tags: ms-access-2010, remote-access, remote-server

What could be the possible issue why MS Access db file loads very slow when opening/accessing it from a remote location? The network team have already checked and found no issues with our connection and cannot pin point the issue.

Comment: Additional info,,, this is a multi user db.

Comment: Additonal info again,,, have tried accessing it using a Citrix connection but the response time went even slow...